# Discord.py add_roles problems

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that gives a role to members when they join. However, it keeps coming up with the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 34, in lol
    await member.add_roles(probation)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 764, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

I have given it the "manage roles permission (see below), but it still comes up with this error.
[image]

Is there a fix for this?
Also my python code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import asyncio

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('Gov')
intents=discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  join_guild = await bot.fetch_guild(793659768606425140)
  probation = join_guild.get_role(838212050332549142)

  
  await member.add_roles(probation)
```

Comment: Are you trying to add roles to the server owner?

Comment: No, I am not, I am trying to add it to new members who joined. It was my alt account though, would that have implications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see any problem on your code. You said bot has `add roles` permission but can you try to check the role that your bot gives to member is on top of your bot's role.

Comment: Does on top mean it is higher than the bot's role? so like in the server settings roles side panels, do I need to make the bot's role above the roles it's trying to give.

Comment: @Cyber-Yosh The role of the bot has to be above the role(s) you want to assign via the bot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
@bot.event async def on_member_join(member):
    channel =discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels,name="channelnamehere")
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='rolenamehere')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await channel.send(f"{member.mention} welcome, you have been assigned {role}!")
```

This should work without having to pull channel IDs and whatnot!
If this doesn't work, my best advice would be checking that your bot is above all the roles you are trying to assign!

Comment: There wasn't a problem with the code it was just that I had the bot's role below the role I was trying to assign, thanks though.